# DOMNode::isEqualNode(): Not yet implemented

Tags: php, xml

I made this function in php to check if a parent XML has already got a xml to insert it or not :

```
function has_xml_node( \DOMElement $needle, \DOMElement $node ) {
    if( $node->hasChildNodes() ){
        foreach ( $node->childNodes as $childNode ) {
            if( $needle->isEqualNode( $childNode ) ){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I got this php error :

> DOMNode::isEqualNode(): Not yet implemented in ...

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55110).

Use `$needle->isSameNode( $childNode );`

BUT it seems to check `'baseURI'` as well so if you have two same tags but from different xml files, `$needle->isSameNode( $childNode );` return `false`.

I made a function to work around this problem.

```
function is_same_node( \DOMNode $node_to_compare, \DOMNode $node_refered, $with_attributes = true ) {
    if( $node_to_compare->tagName !== $node_refered->tagName   )
        return false;
    if( $node_to_compare->nodeValue !== $node_refered->nodeValue   )
        return false;
    if( $node_to_compare->prefix !== $node_refered->prefix   )
        return false;
    if( $with_attributes ){
        if( !$node_to_compare->hasAttributes() && $node_refered->hasAttributes() ){
            return false;
        }else{
            if( !$node_refered->hasAttributes() && $node_to_compare->hasAttributes() ){
                return false;
            }else{
                foreach ( $node_to_compare->attributes as $attribute ){
                    $find_attribute_with_same_value = false;
                    foreach ( $node_refered->attributes as $attribute_refered ){
                        if(
                            $attribute_refered->name === $attribute->name
                            && ( $attribute_refered->value === $attribute->value )
                        ){
                            $find_attribute_with_same_value = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if( !$find_attribute_with_same_value )
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```